# Plotting to 1 figure using multiple functions with Matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a main program `main.py` in which I call various functions with the idea that each function plots something to 1 figure. i.e. all the function plots append detail to the 1 main plot.

Currently I have it set up as, for example:

main.py:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt    

a,b,c = 1,2,3

fig = func1(a,b,c)

d,e,f = 4,5,6

fig = func2(d,e,f)

plt.show()
```

func1:

```
def func1(a,b,c):
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
    ## Do stuff with a,b and c ##
    fig = plt.figure()    
    plt.plot()
    return fig
```

func2:

```
def func2(d,e,f):
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
    ## Do stuff with d,e and f ##
    fig = plt.figure()    
    plt.plot()
    return fig
```

This approach is halfway there but it plots separate figures for each function instead of overlaying them.

How can I obtain 1 figure with the results of all plots overlaid on top of each other?

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a new figure. If you want to plot an existing don't use it in your plotting functions.

Comment: If I remove plt.figure() from the function and plot directly in the function it still creates a new figure for each function.

Comment: I don't believe you :) - Note that you are not plotting anything in your functions, so with your example code it's hard to verify if it works.

Comment: Haha, In the functions there is the line "plt.plot", is that not plotting something? And if that line is not there, how do I create a figure object to send to the main program to plot there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Note that I only create one figure and use the `pyplot` interface to plot to it without ever explicitly obtaining a reference to the figure object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]

def func1(x):
    plt.plot(x)

def func2(x):
    plt.plot(x)

fig = plt.figure()
func1(a)
func2(b)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Please don't use pylab, use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` for state-machine plotting and `import numpy as np` for the math related code.

Comment: @tcaswell, what is the difference between `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `import matplotlib.pylab as plt`? For me it seems that `pylab` does not   pull numpy into the namespace.

Comment: Doing it this way _is_ better than doing a bulk import, but all of numpy is bulk imported into the pylab namespace.  The official position of both mpl and ipython is to discourage/don't really talk about pylab.  It would be great to depreciate it, but there are just too many example out there using it to do so.

Answer (score 4):

It is much better to use the OO interface for this puprose.  See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]

def func1(ax, x):
    ax.plot(x)

def func2(ax, x):
    ax.plot(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
func1(ax, a)
func2(ax, b)
```

It seems silly for simple functions like this, but following this style will make things much much less painful when you want to do something more sophisticated.

Comment: Thank you, that guide was very insightful.

Comment: Is it possible/advisable to write a function with which I could just type ``ax.func1()`` followed by ``ax.func2()``?