# How to keep plot window open and continue plotting in different runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

Assume that for example I want to plot a function like f(x)=a*x**2 in which "a" is parameter, in this way.

First, I plot the function with a=2 and run my code. Second, I sweep "a" to 4 and run my code again. By default Pycharm will plot two figures in two windows but I want them two be in one figure  with different colors. It is easy to do this in MATLAB but in python the only way that I know is to use two "matplotlib.pyplot.plot" commands in my code and define "a" before each, twice. How can I do this as I want?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use OO implementation of matplotlib to create your plots, i.e. `fig,ax = plt.subplots()` and then `ax.plot()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting to 1 figure using multiple functions with Matplotlib, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726931/plotting-to-1-figure-using-multiple-functions-with-matplotlib-python)

Comment: The answer by tacaswell in the flagged duplicate should be the relevant one.

Comment: Possibly it's rather something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420864/how-to-show-matplotlib-plot-in-one-window) what is meant here?